# How to close dbconnection in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a code which Creates a Database Connection as Follows.

```
$dbConn = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUserName, $dbUserPasswrd, $database);  

$strSQL = 'SELECT * 
             FROM Table_Name';

$stmt   = $dbConn->prepare($strSQL);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$dbConn->close();
```

I have created a php page where i call this code.

Now when I see the connections in mysql database using toad GUI it is showing 1 connection during the first time the page loads and count keeps on increasing when the page get refreshed.

1.Why the no of connections increase despite I have mysqli close at the end of code

2.Does using $dbConn->close() help in optimizing performace of DB by reducing no of unused connections

Please explain in brief so everyone can learn some.

[image]

Thanks for Reply

Comment: Did you look up what the variable "connections" means? I suspect it is the total of connections that has been made is, so apart from them being closed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html says:

> **Connections**: The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server.
> **Threads_connected**: The number of currently open connections.

I.e. `connections` counts all attempts to connect that have been made while `threads_connected` is probably the value you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. I tried by running show status like '%onn%'; But there is no change in Threads_connected List

Comment: "But there is no change in Threads_connected List" - please elaborate. It's rather unlikely that you request the variables just in that brief moment when your php script "holds" a connection to the server.

Comment: I tried to run the page after putting in local domain http://192.168.1.18/sample.php I accessed the URl from three different system. The Threads_connected remains the same

Comment: So it's not increasing, your question has been answered? 1. because "connections" is the total number of connections (attempts) that were made, the currently open connection counter does not increase, 2. yes mysqli::close() closes the connection to the server.

Comment: No I removed my code $dbConn->close(); and then also it remains the same.

Comment: When the php script is done remaining resources are collected. I.e. if your script hasn't explicitly closed the connection this happens automagically at the end of the execution (unless you use functions/methods marked as persistent like e.g. explained at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php )